# How to create custom metadata record

Tags: custom-metadata

What is the way to create custom metadata in salesforce org? Are there any specific steps that i should follow?I have tried to create custom metadata via force.com IDE by creating an object with __md appended but it was creating custom object instead with __c appended at the end.I could not find any documentation related to creation of custom metadata records creation.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the below pdf to know all about custom metadata.

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/custom_metadata_types_impl_guide.pdf